# Accessing data and arrays from different function

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a web application through flask where I want to upload an Excel file take all the data in the Excel file and store it in array, or dictionary for data processing in a different function. I am able to read the Excel file and store it in an array, but I was wondering if there's a way to access that data from a different function for processing. If that's possible a pseudo code would help.

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import xlrd, xlwt

app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app)

seller_info = []

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main():

    if request.method == "POST":

        if request.files:
            excel_file = request.files['excel_file']

            wb = pd.ExcelFile(excel_file)
            excel_data = pd.read_excel(wb, "Summary", header=None, nrows=5)

            global seller_info
            for row in excel_data.iterrows():
                seller_info.append(row[1][1])

        return render_template('main.html', seller_info=seller_info)

    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route('/process', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def process():

    return '??'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to be able to pull the data from `seller_info` list and use it later in the `process` method. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: seller_info is already visible to process(). Why can't you see it's content?

Comment: I was just wondering if there's a better way to do it instead of using a global variable because i would have to return the seller_info but I cant return a render_html and a list at the same time

Comment: Pass as argument to the function. Will you use MVC or MVP or else?

Comment: could you provide pseudo code pls I'm new to python and not really sure what that means

Comment: I'm using MVC..

Comment: That's not a python issue. If you call process() from main(), then do process(seller_info) inside main(). seller_info is the argument in this case.

Comment: If you are using MCV than just call seller_info from the Model Class. Your example is very compact and hard to help without knowing a little bit about the hierarchy of you code.

Comment: I just want to access the seller_info array with data appended from main() in the process() function

Comment: So pass seller_info to process(argument). I will show you in an answer but I think you know this.

Comment: I noticed, you are using Flask. Although you can technically use globals and create a stateful web API, I would like to caution you against it. It is generally considered a very poor coding practice and may even break unexpectedly, since in Production, Flask apps may run in multithreaded/multiprocessing environments. Also, I am not sure if you realise, but this global state will be shared among all users of your API. If this isn't just a tiny pet project for fun, but a real app, you should consider researching REST APIs, Databases and ORMs.